# Insert drawn shape over canvas background image

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

In an html document, I have a canvas with a background image, and am drawing a shape and storing it as an object, and then reinserting it as an element of the canvas. As it stands now, the act of reinserting the shape as a canvas element imposes part of the canvas over the background, so that the shape is surrounded by the color of the canvas instead of being drawn over the canvas background. Is there a way to avoid this but still be able to insert the image where I would like? (I know I could save the image as a png and then make its background transparent, but I'd like to do it in the html itself.) I've seen a few things tangential to this, but none that I've found address it directly.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ZLevine/h3mo50w8/4/

I used sample code from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg589516(v=vs.85).aspx to draw the shape.

Code in fiddle:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
<style>
canvas {
    border:1px solid #d3d3d3;
    background-image: white;
    }
</style>
<head>
    <body onload="startGame()">

    <script>
    var ship = new Image();
    var myBackground;

    function startGame() {
        myBackground = new component(656, 541, "http://wallpapercave.com/wp/PU5vVEd.jpg", 0, 0, "background");
        myScore = new component("30px", "Consolas", "white", 280, 40, "text");
        myGameArea.start();
        makeShip();
    }

    var myGameArea = {
        canvas : document.createElement("canvas"),
        start : function() {
            this.canvas.width = 480;
            this.canvas.height = 540;
            this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
            document.body.insertBefore(this.canvas, document.body.childNodes[0]);
            this.frameNo = 0;
            this.interval = setInterval(updateGameArea, 20);  
            },
        clear : function() {
            this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
        },
        stop : function() {
            clearInterval(this.interval);
        }
    }

    function makeShip() {
    ctx = myGameArea.context
            // Draw saucer bottom.
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(28.4, 16.9);
            ctx.bezierCurveTo(28.4, 19.7, 22.9, 22.0, 16.0, 22.0);
            ctx.bezierCurveTo(9.1, 22.0, 3.6, 19.7, 3.6, 16.9);
            ctx.bezierCurveTo(3.6, 14.1, 9.1, 11.8, 16.0, 11.8);
            ctx.bezierCurveTo(22.9, 11.8, 28.4, 14.1, 28.4, 16.9);
            ctx.closePath();
            ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(222, 103, 0)";
            ctx.fill();

            // Draw saucer top.
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(22.3, 12.0);
            ctx.bezierCurveTo(22.3, 13.3, 19.4, 14.3, 15.9, 14.3);
            ctx.bezierCurveTo(12.4, 14.3, 9.6, 13.3, 9.6, 12.0);
            ctx.bezierCurveTo(9.6, 10.8, 12.4, 9.7, 15.9, 9.7);
            ctx.bezierCurveTo(19.4, 9.7, 22.3, 10.8, 22.3, 12.0);
            ctx.closePath();
            ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(51, 190, 0)";
            ctx.fill();
            // Save ship data.
            ship = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, 30, 30);

          }

    function component(width, height, color, x, y, type) {
        this.type  = type;
        if (type == "image" || type == "background") {
        this.image = new Image();
        this.image.src = color;
      }
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        this.speedX = 0;
        this.speedY = 0;    
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;    
        this.update = function() {
            ctx = myGameArea.context;
            if (this.type == "text") {
          ctx.font = this.width + " " + this.height;
          ctx.fillStyle = color;
          ctx.fillText(this.text, this.x, this.y);
        } if (type == "image" || type == "background") {
          ctx.drawImage(this.image, 
            this.x, 
            this.y,
            this.width, this.height);
          if (type == "background") {
            ctx.drawImage(this.image, this.x,
            this.y - this.height,
            this.width, this.height);
          }
        }
        else {
            ctx.fillStyle = color;
            ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
        }
    }
        this.newPos = function() {
            this.x += this.speedX;
            this.y += this.speedY; 
            if (this.type == "background") {
                if (this.y == (this.height)) {
                    this.y = 0;
                }
            }       
        }    
    }

    function updateGameArea() {
        myGameArea.clear();
        myBackground.speedY = 1;
        myBackground.newPos();    
        myBackground.update();
        myGameArea.frameNo += 1;
        ctx.putImageData(ship, 200, 200);
    }

    function everyinterval(n) {
        if ((myGameArea.frameNo / n) % 1 == 0) {return true;}
        return false;
    }


    </script>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ZLevine/h3mo50w8/4/, will also add code in the post itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that using `putImageData()` will draw verbatim what you stored as ImageData when using `getImageData()`. As the ship is surrounded by transparent pixels also these are copied to the canvas overriding what is there.

As markE mentions in his answer, drawing to a temporary canvas is a better solution. All you need to do is to change a couple of places in the code:

```
// Save ship data.
//ship = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, 30, 30);
ship = document.createElement("canvas");  // create canvas
ship.width = ship.height = 30;            // set size
var shipCtx = ship.getContext("2d");      // temp. context
shipCtx.drawImage(ctx.canvas, 0, 0);      // draw ship to canvas
```

Then when you want to draw it back:

```
function updateGameArea() {
    myGameArea.clear();
    myBackground.speedY = 1;
    myBackground.newPos();    
    myBackground.update();
    myGameArea.frameNo += 1;
    //ctx.putImageData(ship, 200, 200);
    ctx.drawImage(ship, 200, 200);        // draw ship from canvas
}
```

**[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/epistemex/h3mo50w8/7/)**

An alternative approach is to draw the shape directly onto the canvas, but using a intermediate canvas will give performance benefits.

Answer (score 1):

Draw the ship on a second in-memory canvas:

```
var memCanvas=document.createElement('canvas');
... draw your ship on the second canvas
```

Then use the second canvas to draw your ship on the main canvas:

```
canvas.drawImage(memCanvas,x,y);
```